# Why is appropos (C-h a) not finding all terms, e.g. backup doesnt find make-backup-file-name-function

Tags: help, apropos

When running `C-h a` then entering `backup`, it lists the following matches, but not all of them (e.g. does not find the `make-backup-file-name-function`)?

```
Buffer-menu-backup-unmark     M-x ... RET
   Move up and cancel all requested operations on buffer on line
   above.
diff-backup           M-x ... RET
   Diff this file with its backup file or vice versa.
dired-backup-diff         M-x ... RET
   Diff this file with its backup file or vice versa.
dired-flag-backup-files       M-x ... RET
   Flag all backup files (names ending with `~') for deletion.
ediff-backup              M-x ... RET
   Run Ediff on FILE and its backup file.
magit-wip-initial-backup-mode M-x ... RET
   Before saving a buffer for the first time, commit to a wip ref.
package-menu-backup-unmark    M-x ... RET
   Back up one line and clear any marks on that package.
```

Comment: `C-h a apropos` will show you all the different variations of `apropos` that you can use ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-h a</kbd> runs `apropos-command`, and so will only show you interactive commands, not variables like `make-backup-file-name-function`. You could use `apropos-user-option` in combination with a non-`nil` value of `apropos-do-all` to search more extensively.

Interactively you can use a prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd> to tell most 'apropos' commands to use their `apropos-do-all` behaviour.

Note that <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos` will show matching functions, variables, and faces.